# Independence between conditional expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $(\Omega, F, P)$ is a sample space, $X$ and $Y$ random variables, and $N$ and $M$ sub sigma algebras of $F$.

1. I know that $E(X\mid N)$ and $E(X\mid\{\emptyset, \Omega\})$ are independent. Generally, if $N$ and $M$ are independent, will $E(X\mid N)$ and $E(X\mid M)$ be independent? What are some conditions on $N$, $M$ and $X$ that can make $E(X\mid N)$ and $E(X\mid M)$  independent?
2. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, are $E(X\mid N)$ and $E(Y\mid N)$ independent? What are some conditions on $N$, $X$ and $Y$ that can make $E(X\mid N)$ and $E(Y\mid N)$  independent?

Thanks.

Comment: Recall the definition of the conditional expectation, your first question can be trivially answered.

Comment: right. @Domink. thanks. How about the second question? I was wondering if E(X|N) must be measurable wrt both sigma(X)  and N?

Comment: In general it is only measurable wrt $N$, as the example $N = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ shows.

Comment: Is there relation between $\sigma(E(X|N))$ and  $\sigma(\sigma(X) \cap N)$? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420189/determine-measurability-of-exn-or-even-sigmaexn

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question: Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables that assume the values $0$ and $1$ each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Setting $N = X + Y$ you get
$$E[X \mid X + Y] = E[Y \mid X + Y] = \frac{X + Y}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks. how do you determine E[X∣X+Y]?

Comment: If $X + Y$ is $0$ resp. $2$, then you know that $X$ is $0$ resp. $1$. In the case $X + Y = 1$ you have equal probabilites for $X = 0$ and $X = 1$, so in the mean you get $\frac{1}{2}$. This is the intuitive explanation, based on this you can prove that $\frac{X+Y}{2}$ actually satisfies the properties of the conditional expectation. Another way should be using the fact that $E[X + Y \mid X + Y] = X + Y$, then the claim follows from $E[X\mid X + Y] = E[Y \mid X + Y]$. However, I haven't been able to prove the last identity rigorously - I believe it should hold by symmetry.