# Determine measurability of E(X|N) or even $\sigma(E(X|N))$?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $(\Omega, F, P)$ is a sample space, $X$ a random variable, and $N$ a sub sigma algebra of $F$.

How can we determine  $\sigma(E(X|N))$?

How is $\sigma(E(X|N))$ related to $\sigma(X)$ and $N$?

$E(X|N))$ is $N$-measurable. But must $E(X|N)$ be $\sigma(X)$-measurable?

What is the relation between $\sigma(E(X|N))$ and $\sigma(\sigma(X) \cap N)$? Are they equal, or is one a subset of the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$E(X|N)$ need not to be $\sigma(X)$-measurable. Say, let $\Omega = \{\omega_i, i = 1,2,3,4\}$, $P$ is uniform, $N = \sigma(\{\omega_1,\omega_2\})$, $X = \mathbf{1}_{\omega_1}$. Then $E(X|N) = \frac12 \mathbf{1}_{\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}}$, so $\sigma(E(X|N)) = N$, which has a trivial intersection with $\sigma(X)$.

Comment: how do you determine σ(E(X|N))? Are σ(E(X|N)) and σ(σ(X)∩N) equal, or one is the subset of the other?

Comment: Thanks. How do you determine E(X|N)? Some general rule?

Comment: @Tim, this is the conditional expectation given the partition $\Omega = \{\omega_1,\omega_2\}\cup\{\omega_3,\omega_4\}$: $$E(X|N) = E(X\mathbf{1}_{\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}})/P(\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}) + E(X\mathbf{1}_{\{\omega_3,\omega_4\}})/P(\{\omega_3,\omega_4\}).$$

Comment: Are σ(E(X|N)) and σ(σ(X)∩N) equal, or is one a subset of the other?

Comment: @Tim, as I wrote, $\sigma(X)\cap N = \{\varnothing, \Omega\}$ (you don't have to generate a $\sigma$-algebra, as this is already one), while $\sigma(E(X|N)) = N$.